# Cmajor11(#13) same as C(dominant)11?

Tags: theory, harmony, chord-theory, jazz

I was learning about extension chords where I stumbled upon a question: if we play `Cmajor11(sharp 13)`, wouldn't that have the note `B flat` which is supposed to be there in dominant chord? Shouldn't that make the `Cmajor11` into a `Cdominant11` or something like that?

I tried experimenting around and even thought that it could be both, but then I also had the question, if `sharp 13` in a `major 7` chord can be considered an avoid note or not.

Comment: @Aaron’ answer sums up things clearly, +1. I would like to offer a few comments. First, in several decades of being a musician I have never encountered a #13 chord so this chord is more theoretical than practical. Secondly, 11th chords with a major 3rd are also extremely rare because for example, in a C chord the E and F in the chord create a very dissonant b9 interval. It is much more common to use a sus4, replacing the 3rd with the 4th. Major chords, either maj7 or dominant 7 much more commonly will use a #11 instead of an 11 for more of a Lydian sound.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - interesting (maybe) that a dom 13 chord *already* contains that A# (Bb) note, and often sounds better without the 11th - for the reasons you quote. Like you, never had the misfortune to meet a maj 11#13 chord in real life. But just by spelling, they're not the same.

Answer (score 2):

A complete CMaj11(#13) chord is spelled `C E G B D F A#`, and a C11 (that is, Cdominant11) is spelled `C E G Bb D F`.

So these are not equivalent, because one contains `B natural` and the other does not.

However, it's true that both chords contain the enharmonically equivalent (i.e., they represent the same pitch) `A#` and `Bb`. The difference in spelling relates to technical/theoretical differences in how those pitches are used in context.

In jazz/pop contexts, chord spelling is often more a matter of convenience as ease of reading/understanding, but the underlying theory suggests that a `#13` (`A#`) should move upwards; whereas a `b7` (`Bb`) should move downwards.

As to whether the `#13` would be an avoid note against a `major7` chord -- more likely than not. It would be highly dissonant against the major seventh (`A#` against `B`), but could be quite useful in an appropriate musical context.

---

@JohnBelzaguy's comment on the OP is recommended reading. It explains how these chords are used (or not used, as the case may be) in practice.